# Assign an unused return-value of a method that both sets and returns a value?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Several methods in matplotlib both return a value, and set an attribute of an object. For instance, `.yaxis.set_major_locator()` which both changes the y-axis of a plot, and returns the y-axis.

In a piece of code, I have the following statement:

```
axes.yaxis.set_major_locator(DayLocator())
```

with `axes` a variable to which I assigned a subplot.

Since I use `axes` but have no use for the y-axis itself, the return-value of `axes.yaxis.set_major_locator(DayLocator())` is not assigned.

This seems perfectly fine for me, but pylint of course complains about this.

Two questions:

1. Can I safely ignore this warning, or should I assign it nevertheless?
2. More generally, what's the benefit of a setter_method that also returns a value other than None?

Comment: It is conventional in Python for a method to *either* change the state of the object and `return None` (explicitly or, by ending the method without an explicit return statement, implicitly), *or* leave the state unchanged and return something. Going against that convention makes your code harder to read and understand for those familiar with it.

Comment: That's what I thought as well, which is precisely why I got confused by these methods in matplotlib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer: In this case, ignore this warning or configure pylint to ignore it.

---

For what it's worth `ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(...)` returns `None` as it should by convention.

However, there are other cases such as `ax.set_ylim(...)` that do return the new limits in addition to modifying the axes.

As far as why things as `ax.set_ylim` will return the set value, for matplotlib it's only done in cases where the function *may not honor the value you pass in*.

For example, if you set the y-limits, depending on the values of `aspect` and `adjustable`, those exact limits may not be honored. Therefore, `set_ylim` returns the limits that were actually set.

Comment: Right. As it happens, I partly got a pylint error due to a typo and then ended up looking at several methods related to axes in matplotlib.